# pyinstaller, poppler, and other dependencies

Tags: python, pyinstaller, poppler

I am a new developer, and probably well beyond my scope right now. I have made a script that uses several dependencies I had to install on my personal PC, and I cannot install them on my work PC. I know the code itself works as intended when I use it at home with all dependencies available. This is where I get beyond my scope as I do not know how to include these dependencies with my distribution version. I have used pyinstaller to attempt to "catch" the dependencies when compiling to a .exe, but to no avail.

Here is a snippet of my dependencies

```
import pytesseract 
import sys 
import tkinter as tk
import os 

from PIL import Image 
from tkinter import Button
from pdf2image import convert_from_path 
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import ImageTk as itk

poppler_path = r"D:\7-10\Receiver Reader V0.1\poppler\bin"
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'D:\7-10\Receiver Reader V0.1\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'
```

Here is the error I get on the work PC

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\pdf2image\pdf2image.py", line 409, in pdfinfo_from_path
  File "subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
  File "ReceiverReaderV1.py", line 69, in run_reader_prog
  File "site-packages\pdf2image\pdf2image.py", line 89, in convert_from_path
  File "site-packages\pdf2image\pdf2image.py", line 430, in pdfinfo_from_path
pdf2image.exceptions.PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?
```

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Thank you!

Comment: So you get the problem when you build an exe then try to run?

Comment: correct. I am building the .exe on my personal computer using --one-dir and then putting the entire folder onto a flash drive. I then try to run the code on my work computer and get the above errors.

Comment: maybe try building it with `--onefile`

Comment: And what is poppler? if it's an different file/exe that gets called, then you need to include it in your datas

Comment: Another error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
  File "ReceiverReaderV1.py", line 68, in run_reader_prog
  File "site-packages\pdf2image\pdf2image.py", line 89, in convert_from_path
  File "site-packages\pdf2image\pdf2image.py", line 434, in pdfinfo_from_path
pdf2image.exceptions.PDFPageCountError: Unable to get page count.
Syntax Warning: May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway)
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table`